# Codename One combobox styling

Tags: combobox, codenameone

Please, see picture bolow: [image]

I cannot get rid of white paddings/margins in combobox popup. I have two custom containers in designer called DropdownItem and DropdownItemSelected, Fisheye renderer type for ComboBox renderer. As you may see in combobox selected item is displayed just fine. However, in I cannot get combobox popup displayed without white paddings. I have actually used PopupContentPane to add blue border around popup, I also have border set to empty, all margins/paddings set to 0 for following UIIDs: PopupItem, PopupFocus, DropdownItem and DropdownItemSelected. PopupContentPane has also all paddings/margins set to 0. Also see my contants:

[image]

I went through source code and cannot find any other useful UIID I can style in order to remove these white paddings. Can someone help me with this?

**Update:**

Might be helpful - see below how popup looks like when PopupContentPane border sickness is set to 2px:

[image]

**Update 2:**

Almost there. After setting `listItemGapInt` constant to 0 I managed to remove gaps between list items. See screenshot below.

[image]

I still cannot find out how to remove 2 pixel gap on the right and don't know where it's coming from. Would appreciate any thoughts/ideas.

**Update 3:**

I eventually found where two pixels are coming from.

com.codename1.ui.ComboBox class, lines 289-290

```
289 int listW = Math.max(getWidth() , l.getPreferredW());
290 listW = Math.min(listW + getUIManager().getLookAndFeel().getVerticalScrollWidth(), 
             parentForm.getContentPane().getWidth());
```

In my particular case, `listW`=630px and in line 290 listW is recalculated as Math.min(630 + 2, 768), where 2px is width of vertical scroll.

As far as can say, scroll bar should be a part ComboBox popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to remove unwanted gaps. As I mentioned in 'update 2', listItemGapInt should be set to 0 in order to remove horizontal gaps.

Vertical gap was related to scroll bar however it was not clear that it's a vertical scroll bar that creates that gap. After I set paddings to 0 for `Scroll` UIID, vertical gap has gone.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In regard to update 3, this is a bug but not because it should be in the container. The list is scrollable so this should be a part of the list however the call should be to `l.getSideGap()` and not to `getVerticalScrollWidth()`.

This will allow you to hide that by setting the scroll bars to visible false etc. We'll fix that for the next update.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Fortunately Codename One is open-source and can debug down pretty much any problem )